# Numpy: np.linalg.tensorsolve and tensorinv error: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square

Tags: numpy

I have the following ndarray (which is stacked by 351 3x3 matrices)

```
tensor = np.ones((351,3,3))
b = np.ones((351,3))
```

Applying a function such as :

```
np.linalg.tensorinv(tensor)
np.linalg.tensorsolve(tensor,b)
```

Gives me the following error:
"{LinAlgError}Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square"

Why does that error occur? I mean the last two dimensions are square (3x3). This even do not work with tensor.T (which is 3x3x351). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sense in which the [tensorinv](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.tensorinv.html) operation defines square dimensions is somewhat unusual. `tensorinv` takes a parameter `ind` and a tensor is "square" if the product of the indices up to (but not including) `ind` and the product of the indices from `ind` to the last index are equal, i.e. `prod(tensor.shape[:ind]) == prod(tensor.shape[ind:])`. This is useful for defining inverses of tensor operations or solving tensor contraction equations, but based on the shape of your examples, I expect this isn't what you are trying to do.

You seem to be wanting to solve 315 different linear systems of equations Ax=b. You should be able to do this with just `np.linalg.solve(tensor, b)` (though not with your examples in the question, as your tensor of all ones would be a bunch of singular matrices). Rewriting your example to make `tensor` smaller and a collection of identity matrices rather than all ones:

```
>>> temp=np.eye(3)
>>> tensor=np.repeat(temp[np.newaxis,:,:],4,axis=0)
>>> tensor.shape
(4, 3, 3)
>>> b=np.ones((4,3))
>>> b
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
>>> np.linalg.solve(tensor,b)
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: Yepp you are absolutely right. np.linalg.solve does its job. Thank you